# Additive decomposition of product of Brownian motions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ be independent standard Brownian motions and set
$$
X_t=\int_0^tW_{1}\ dW_{2} \text{ and } Y_t=\int_0^tW_{2}\ dW_{1}.
$$

The product rule shows that
$$
W_{1,t}W_{2,t}=X_t + Y_t.
$$
For a fixed $t$ I would like to understand the nature of this additive decomposition of the random variable $W_{1,t}W_{2,t}$.

### Questions:

What can be said about the (joint) distribution of $(X_t, Y_t)$?

More specifically:

- What is the marginal distribution of $X_t$ and $Y_t$?
- Can $X_t$ and $Y_t$ be expressed in terms of $W_{1,t}$  and $W_{2,t}$ alone?
- What is the correlation between $X_t$ and $Y_t$?
- What are the characteristic functions of $X_t$ and $Y_t$?

Or anything else which may shed some light on the joint distribution.

Beyond "raw" results I would appreciate references to literature, where I can learn more about ways to tackle those and similar questions.

Comment: The product $W_{1,t}W_{2,t}$ is a martingale, which you have written as the sum of two martingales $X_t$ and $Y_t$.  But what do you mean by "*the* Martingale decomposition"?

Comment: I mean this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_representation_theorem but of course in the multivariate case. Maybe "representation" is better than "decomposition"? And about "the": I assumed (without knowing much about it)) that this representation was unique, but this might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, the vector process $(W_2,W_1)$ is the predictable integrand in the martingale representation of the product $W_1W_2$ in the filtration of the two-dimensional Brownian motion $(W_1,W_2)$.

Comment: Great! Can you give a reference for this result or indicate how this can be shown? (and post this as a partial answer?)